# Form not submitting values

Tags: php, forms

Ok so, I am a self taught coder, so no need to be overly rude if I am missing something lol. This is the first ever form I have created, and I have the css, html, and php set up. My issue is whenever I hit the submit button, all it does is reload the page and sends no data. I have honestly checked out the other forums here for answers but the things I have found in other forums, I have tried, but it hasn't worked. I will leave my code below, if anyone could tell me why its not submitting the values that would be a huge help.

```
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta name="description" content="Contact Us">
    <meta name="keywords" content="Contact Us">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1,user-scalable=no">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge,chrome=1">
    <meta name="HandheldFriendly" content="true">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Barlow+Condensed" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="ContactUs.css">
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <!--[if IE 6]>
    <style type="text/css">html .group { height: 1%; }</style>
    <![endif]-->
    <!--[if IE 7]>
    <style type="text/css">*:first-child+html .group { min-height: 1px; } </style>
    <![endif]-->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]> 
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/html5shiv/3.7.3/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
</head>
```

This is my HTML

```
<div class="global_container_">
    <header class="header-box-holder"></header>
    <div class="header-left"></div>
    <div class="header-center"></div>
    <div class="l-constrained">
    <div class="main-content-wrapper">
    <div class="header-image"><a href="http://www.fykemusic.com/"><img src="images/header_box.jpg" /></a>
    <div id="form-main">
    <div id="form-div">
    <form method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>">
        <p class="name">
            <input name="name" type="text" class="validate[required,custom[onlyLetter],length[0,100]] feedback-input" placeholder="Name" id="name" />
        </p>
        <p class="email">
            <input name="email" type="text" class="validate[required,custom[email]] feedback-input" id="email" placeholder="Email" />
        </p>
        <p class="message">
            <textarea name="message" class="validate[required,length[6,300]] feedback-input" id="comment" placeholder="Message"></textarea>
        </p>
        <div class="submit">
            <input type="submit" value="Submit" id="button-blue"/>
            <div class="ease"></div>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

This is my PHP

```
<?php 
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $message = $_POST['message'];
    $formcontent="From: $name \n Message: $message";
    $recipient = "searaadair@hotmail.com";
    $subject = "Contact Form";
    $mailheader = "From: $email \r\n";
    mail($recipient, $subject, $formcontent, $mailheader) or die("Error!");
    echo "Thank You!";
}
?>
```

Comment: Most likely lucumts answer is correct but without seeing the full picture it's impossible to know. Where is your PHP located in the document? Can you post the full code? There are some other issues I see in the html. For example, the tag <html> is in the middle of the code.

Comment: Also, is that HTML actually in a PHP file? If not, your form is pointing to an invalid URL and won't actually POST anywhere.

Comment: Yes, my html and PHP are in a PHP file, and the php is located at the bottom of the code. I have a hunch that it might need to be put somewhere else, am I right about that? Or does that matter? and thanks John. I removed that!

Comment: I updated with rest of my code, minus CSS, as I don't think that is the issue

Comment: Right inside the if statement, var_dump($_POST);exit; does the output show up when you post?

Comment: @mkaatman you mean like this? if(var_dump($_POST);exit;))

Comment: This might be a minor issue, but have you tried having just one form tag rather than two? (ie leave the first one and get rid of `<form class="form" id="form1">`?

Comment: @MosesKirathe someone commented that earlier and I actually updated that on my end and it didn't work unfortunately...I will update on here to.

Comment: I think it you might be trying to submit data whose form lacks the method and action attributes. Also, in referring to @JohnT's comment, why do you have the <html> tag in the middle of the code?

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51111445/getting-an-error-object-not-found-error-404/51111647

Comment: @MehulV. I looked through that post before posting this and my submit button layout is correct.

Comment: try `<input type="submit" value="Submit" name="submit" id="button-blue"/>`

Comment: Does it work to just echo "Hello World"; outside of your if{} in your PHP? Just to confirm that PHP is working properly.

Comment: @JohnT actually no it doesnt, so there is an issue with my PHP code then?

Comment: @JohnT wait, when I tried to echo Hello World, it made my "Thank You!" echo inside my {} pop up instead, so I removed the Thank you echo and tried it, and now the form is going through...

Comment: @Seara Adair So it's working now?

Comment: @JohnT yes, thank you! I read my error logs to and found a couple other things and changed those. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this for your PHP template. I noticed some `<divs>` were missing their closing tags, so I fixed that. The most peculiar issue was how you had two `<form>` tags, and only one of them were closing. These two lines here...

```
<form method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>">
<form class="form" id="form1">
```

Must be inside the same tag.

```
<form method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" class="form" id="form1">
```

Try it with the following PHP. You also had a strange stray `<html>` tag.

```
</head>
<div class="global_container_">
    <header class="header-box-holder"></header>

    <div class="header-left"></div>

    <div class="header-center"></div>

    <div class="l-constrained">
    <div class="main-content-wrapper">
        <div class="header-image"><a href="http://www.fykemusic.com/"><img 
src="images/header_box.jpg" /></a></div>
        <div id="form-main">
            <div id="form-div">
                <form method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" class="form" id="form1">
                    <p class="name">
                        <input name="name" type="text" 
    class="validate[required,custom[onlyLetter],length[0,100]] feedback-input" 
    placeholder="Name" id="name" />
                    </p>

                    <p class="email">
                        <input name="email" type="text" 
    class="validate[required,custom[email]] feedback-input" id="email" 
    placeholder="Email" />
                    </p>

                    <p class="message">
                        <textarea name="message" class="validate[required,length[6,300]] 
feedback-input" id="comment" placeholder="Message"></textarea>
                    </p>

                    <div class="submit">
                        <input type="submit" value="Submit" id="button-blue"/>
                        <div class="ease"></div>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: Thank you for that, I tried replacing it with what you provided and unfortunately I am still not able to get it to work....

Answer (score 0):

Ensure that your HTML have the `.php` file extension, since you are printing `$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']` on the form's `action` attribute. That will not happen if you're using `.html` as file extension. I also noticed that you seemed to be using a javascript validation plugin (through the `class` attribute), double check the submit event for that as well.

Comment: it is correctly named, it us under formmail.php. I am probably going to remove the validation for now actually, so I will see if that changes anything. Will add it back when I can at least get the form to submit lol