# Getting an error: object not found error 404

Tags: php, mysqli

I have been working on an administration login page using php and mysqli. When I try and use my localhost I get this error:
Object not found!
The requested URL was not found on this server. If you entered the URL manually please check your spelling and try again.

If you think this is a server error, please contact the webmaster.

Error 404
localhost
Apache/2.4.29 (Win32) OpenSSL/1.1.0g PHP/7.2.0

I checked the path and nothing is wrong, so I can't figure out why it will not show up.

Her is my login info:

localhost:10080/pinkys_pearls/storeadmin/admin_login.php

Everything is in the htdocs folder (using Xampp) and still can't figure thisout. Here is the code I am using:

```
       <?php

session_start();

if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {

    include "../storescripts/connect_to_mysql.php";
    $con = mysqli_connect("$db_host","$db_username","$db_pass","$db_name");
    $username = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['username']);
    $password = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['password']);

    //Error handler
    //Check for empty fields
    if (empty($username) || empty($password)) {
        header("Location: ../admin_login.php?admin_login=empty");
        exit();
    } else {
        //Check if charactors are valid
        if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z0-9]*$/", $username) || !preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z0-9]*$/", $password)) {
            header("Location: ../admin_login.php?admin_login=invalid");
        exit();
        } else {
            $sql = "SELECT * FROM admin WHERE username = '$username'' AND password = '$password'";
            $result = mysqli_query($con, $sql);
            $resultCheck = mysqli_num_rows($result);
            if ($resultCheck < 1) {
                header("Location: ../admin_login.php?admin_login=invalid");
                exit();
            } else {
                if ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {

                    $_SESSION['manager'] = $row['username'];
                    $_SESSION['manager_pwd'] = $row['password'];
                    header("Location: admin_index.php"); //relocate to index 
 page
                    exit();
                } else{
                    echo 'username and password invalid. Please try again';
                }
            }
        }
    }

} else{
    header("Location: ../admin_login.php");
    exit();
}
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Admin Log In </title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../style.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />
</head>

<body>
<div align="center" id="mainWrapper">
  <div id="pageContent"><br />
    <div align="left" style="margin-left:24px;">
      <h2>Please Log In To Manage the Store</h2>
      <form id="form1" name="form1" method="POST" action="admin_login.php">
        User Name:<br />
          <input name="username" type="text" id="username" size="40" />
        <br /><br />
        Password:<br />
       <input name="password" type="password" id="password" size="40" />
       <br />
       <br />
       <br />

         <input type="submit" name="button" id="button" value="Log In" />

      </form>
      <p>&nbsp; </p>
    </div>
  <br />
  <br />
  <br />
  </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

I have been over this a hundred times looking for the solution. Can someone tell me how to correct the problem?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You submit button name is `button`

```
<input type="submit" name="button" id="button" value="Log In" />
```

So you have to check condition with `button`

```
if(isset($_POST['button'])) {
     //code goes here
}
else{
     // here....  
}
```

The type attribute specifies the type of `<input>` element to display [Read more](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_type.asp).
and The name attribute specifies the name of an `<input>` element [Read More](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_name.asp).

Comment: I did what you both said and I was able to log in. Thank you very much!

Comment: @SamuelJaycox Plz, accept this answer if you found a solution from my answer! https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Certainly when you run this page, it is going to redirect you to `../admin_login.php` if `$_POST['submit']` is not set. So if you are getting this error the page `admin_login.php` is not found in the appropriate location in your server. Do not redirect in the `else` section as `$_POST['submit']` will never be set when you first load the page.

Here is the conflict.

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    //your code
}else{ 
    header("Location: ../admin_login.php");
    exit();
}
```